# Docker-machine resource limit

Tags: docker

I made docker-machine like below

> docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count 2
>   --virtualbox-memory 2048 default

As I known, docker container is on this docker-machine host.
I made some container on this docker-machine host, and somehow seems docker container use more resource than setting resource on docker-machine (actullay cpu).

1. Is this possible? If so, What is actually do 'virtualbox-memory' and 'cpu-count'?
2. Here is 'docker stats' output. Why is cpu usage more than 100%?
   [image]

Comment: If it's 2 cores allocated it would reach the 200% max.

Comment: max of sum of all container cpu usage will be 200%?

Comment: Every CPU core allocated to every container would have 100% max utilisation in that output.

Comment: @zerkms could you post your comment as an answer, then this question can be marked resolved

Comment: @thaJeztah done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `docker stats` every container gets 100% added to the `CPU%` column for every core allocated.

It means couple of things:

- the percentage per line might be more than 100%
- the total sum of percentages can be more than number of cores in the server